# Is there a bijection from indecomposable to irreducible set partitions?

Tags: co.combinatorics

A partition of $[n]$ is indecomposable if no subset of its blocks partitions $[k]$ with $k \in [n-1]$. Irreducible set partitions are defined at http://oeis.org/A055105 . Both are counted by http://oeis.org/A074664 . Is any bijection between them known?

Comment: If I understand these correctly, indecomposable is, for each $k$, there exists a block which contains numbers both $\geq k$ and $\leq k$. Irreducible is, for each $k$, there exists a block that does not contain numbers both $\geq k$ and $\leq k$. And they are equinumerous? Interesting!

Comment: For $n=3$, I see four irreducible partitions out of five, namely $\big\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\big\}$, $\big\{\{1,2\},\{3\}\big\}$, $\big\{\{1,3\},\{2\}\big\}$, $\big\{\{1\},\{2,3\}\big\}$. But I only see two indecomposable partitions: $\big\{\{1\, 3\},\{2\}\big\}$, $\big\{\{1,2,3\}\big\}$. What am I missing?

Comment: @Will: I guess you mean $>$ instead of $\ge$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike  Zabrocki has kindly addressed me to the following note http://www.billchen.org/publications/2011_P7_Unsplitable/2011_P7_Unsplitable.pdf  where the bijection is built (here "atomic"="indecomposable" and "unsplittable"="irreducible"). Note that the correct version of the definition of splittable or reducible partition (page 3 on top)  allows different lengths for the reducing partitions (a small but important detail that will be fixed in the OEIS link).